# How To Hide .html?

Tags: html

Me and my team working on a final year project and we hosted our site in firebase
but when we go from one page to another page it shows .html at the end of file

How It Shows:-

> site.abc/Home.html

How I want:--

> site.abc/Home

so how Can I hide .html, the project is in just HTML Not in PHP

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. You're talking about routing requests, which is entirely dependent on your backend stack.

Comment: i already tried .htaccess codes but it is not working

Comment: htaccess doesn't work on firebase, you need firebase.json

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to use folders. Have a directory for each page, like `Home`, and place and `index.html` file inside. Then link to `website.com/Home` and it will automatically serve the index page, while leaving the `.html` out of the URL.
**Note:** This will cause a hiccup on your local machine. When you click on the link it will take you to a directory page and you'll have to manually click on the folder. But again, this only happens on local.

Comment: So if i deploy it on firebase then that problem will never comes right?

Comment: @Raju, yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

Because you're in firebase you'll need `firebase.json`, not `.htaccess`. First create the `firebase.json` file (if not exists).

Then, add this code to your `firebase.json` -

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": true
  }
}
```

`"cleanUrls": true` removes extension from the files

`"trailingSlash":true` adds a trailing slash at the url end (e.g. converts `example.com/index` to `example.com/index/`). Add this if you want a trailing slash `/` at the end.

You can read more about firebase.json [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#firebase-json_example)